# Session vs Token Based Authentication

Tags: mongodb, session, jwt, go, tokens

Estoy desarrollando los servicios para el inicio de sesión en un sitio web. He estado leyendo sobre diferentes formas de administrar la sesion de los usuarios. En un principio, iba a desarrollar un sistema basado en sesión, sin embargo, muchos desarrolladores dicen que su principal desventaja es que requiere acceder a la Base de datos. Y que eso puede ser un cuello de botellas y reducir el performance.

Entonces comencé a leer sobre la autenticación usando JWT que permite a los usuarios autenticarse sin tener que acceder a la base de datos. Sin embargo, si un usuario desea mantenerse conectado en el sistema, necesito usar un refresh token, debido al tiempo de expiracion del JWT. Los refresh tokens segun tengo entendido también se deben almacenarse en la base de datos. Entonces volvemos al mismo problema de antes.

¿Hay alguna manera de autenticar a los usuarios siendo completamente independiente de la base de datos?

Comment: La pregunta luce amplia y basada en opiniones lo cual generaría su cierre

Comment: Revisa por favor [ask] para que conozcas como podrías realizar tu pregunta en el sitio y obtengas la ayuda requerida, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con cualquiera de las opciones, variables de sesion o tokens JWT vas a conectarte a la base de datos, al menos la primera vez que se loguea para verificar el usuario y el hash del password.

Ninguna de estas opciones genera cuellos de botellas en entornos bien planificados y programados.

Los tokens, ya sea JWT o cualquier otro se crearon por dos motivos principalmente:

1. La necesidad de poder usar las API como servicios de autenticación sin comprometer la seguridad de la cuenta, por ejemplo, cuando ves que un sitio te permite loguearte con tu cuenta de Google, Facebook, Twitter o cualquier otra API que ofrezca este servicio, el login de la cuenta se hace contra el proveedor para que los terceros no conozcan tu password real, entonces estas les dan estos tokens que gestionan la auteticación y los permisos de lo que pueden realizar.
2. Si puede existir un cuello de botella, o más bien un desbordamiento de recursos del servidor cuando se maneja variables de sesion, porque estas se almacenan en la memoria RAM de tu servidor, y por lo general un servidor promedio puede aguantar unas 10.000-25.000 sesion activas, obviamente dependiendo de cuanta RAM tenga y la cantidad de información que cargas en estas variables puede ser menos o más, el problema venía con las compañías masivas, imaginate que en facebook facil tendrá 1.000 millones de sesiones activas al mismo tiempo, tal vez más porque cada persona por lo general tiene dos sesiones vivas minimo, el movil y la pc, lo mismo ocurre con Google y otros, toda es información es practicamente imposible almacenar en la RAM, además que estos siempre están en varios servidores por el mundo y crear variables de sesiones por todos lados sería complicado y excesivamente caro. Entonces la solución fue crear estos tokens que almacenan toda esa información en el lado cliente, y el servidor únicamente comprueba con cada petición que sea un token válido y no modificado.

En conclusión, si tu sistema va ser usado por una cantidad pequeña de usuarios al mismo tiempo, ambas soluciones son muy válidas. Si vas a tener usuarios masivos estás obligado a usar algún token.

Comment: Consejo: evita responder a preguntas basadas en opiniones pues terminan cerradas

Comment: Ayúdanos respondiendo preguntas que fueron realizadas con respecto a [ask], saludos.

Comment: Aunque ya te lo han comentado, lo recalco: *evita responder preguntas basadas en opiniones*. Tu respuesta, aunque extensa, no aporta nada concreto, sólo es tu opinión, como lo puede ser la de cualquier otro profesional. No lo tomes a mal, el problema no es la respuesta, el problema es la pregunta. Saludos